# why is chainlink release 1.4.0 is not retrievable anymore through brownie package manager?

Tags: chainlink, brownie

`brownie compile` returns the following error due to this line in `brownie-config.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
    - smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.4.0
```

the release tag clearly exists though: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/tree/v1.4.0

updating the version in the yaml file to 1.6.0 gets rid of this issue.

why is 1.4.0 not retrievable (anymore)?

```
ValueError: Invalid version for this package. Available versions are:
test-2020-03-03, 2.0.0-beta0, 1.13.1-beta0, 1.13.0, 1.13.0-rc2, 1.13.0-rc1, 1.13.0-rc0, 1.13.0-healthchecks-20230320, 1.13.0-healthchecks1, 1.13.0-beta4, 1.13.0-beta3, 1.13.0-beta2, 1.13.0-beta1, 1.13.0-beta0, 1.12.1-rc0, 1.12.1-beta4, 1.12.1-beta3, 1.12.1-beta2, 1.12.1-beta1, 1.12.1-beta0, 1.12.0, 1.12.0-rc2, 1.12.0-rc1, 1.12.0-rc0, 1.12.0-clf-20230224, 1.12.0-clf-20230217, 1.12.0-clf-20230214, 1.12.0-beta2, 1.12.0-beta1, 1.12.0-beta0, 1.12.0-base-rc1, 1.12.0-base-rc0, 1.11.1-rc1, 1.11.1-rc0, 1.11.1-beta2, 1.11.1-beta1, 1.11.1-beta0, 1.11.0, 1.11.0-rc6, 1.11.0-rc5, 1.11.0-rc4, 1.11.0-rc3, 1.11.0-rc2, 1.11.0-rc1, 1.11.0-rc0, 1.11.0-clf-20230127, 1.11.0-beta4, 1.11.0-beta3, 1.11.0-beta2, 1.11.0-beta1, 1.11.0-beta0, 1.10.0, 1.10.0-rc0, 1.10.0-beta5, 1.10.0-beta4, 1.10.0-beta3, 1.10.0-beta2, 1.10.0-beta1, 1.10.0-beta0, 1.9.0, 1.9.0-rc1, 1.9.0-beta1, 1.9.0-beta0, 1.8.1, 1.8.1-rc1, 1.8.1-rc0, 1.8.1-debug-keepers-opt-arb, 1.8.1-beta2, 1.8.1-beta1, 1.8.1-beta0, 1.8.0, 1.8.0-rc1, 1.8.0-rc0, 1.8.0-debug-keepers-opt-arb, 1.8.0-beta3, 1.8.0-beta2, 1.8.0-beta1, 1.8.0-beta0, 1.7.2-beta2, 1.7.2-beta1, 1.7.2-beta0, 1.7.1, 1.7.1-rc1, 1.7.1-rc0, 1.7.0, 1.7.0-rc3, 1.7.0-rc2, 1.7.0-rc1, 1.7.0-rc0, 1.7.0-beta0, 1.6.0, 1.6.0-rc1, 1.6.0-rc0, 1.6.0-debug-vrfv1-rinkeby-broadcast-log, 1.6.0-debug-vrfv1-listener-logs, 1.6.0-debug-multikeys-timeout, 1.6.0-debug-multikeys-pprof, 1.6.0-debug-multikeys, 1.6.0-beta3, 1.6.0-beta2
```

Comment: ah i count exactly 100 entries in the list of available versions. is this limited on purpose? why?

Comment: Can you create an issue in Brownie's Github? I think this maybe an issue in package management in Brownie.

Comment: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1679